# What is the effect of applied magnetic field on absorption spectrum?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, absorption

> Upon application of a weak magnetic field, a line in the microwave absorption spectrum of rigid rotor splits into $3$ lines. The quantum number $(J)$ of the rotational energy level from which the transition originates is
>
> (**a**) $0$
> (**b**) $1$
> (**c**) $2$
> (**d**) $3$

Can anyone explain the answer (**a**) for this?
For rotational levels, each level is $(2J+1)$ fold degenerate. According to that, the answer should be (**b**).

Comment: Transition occurs between levels

Comment: @Alchimista Do you mean that there is a transition from J=0 to J=1?

Comment: Yes else you would get more lines